Error using \verb in a footnote in Beamer
I know we need to use fragile when using \verb in beamer as explained here.
But even with fragile, I get the following error when using \verb in a footnote.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.2 \end{frame}
               
? 

How can I fix this?
A minimal example is
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Title}
Text\footnote{\verb|\int|}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


You can use \footnote{\texttt{\textbackslash int}} instead

\verb and {verbatim} do not do well inside other commands.  In fact, \verb doesn't work in a footnote even in article, let alone in beamer.  (TBH, I'm surprised it works in a frame, even with fragile.)
But in this case, we can get the (desired?) output without \verb: just use \footnote{\ttfamily\textbackslash int}.  The first command changes to the \verb style font, and the second gives us the intended backslash.  (This does give two warnings about the font that a more knowledgable person may help fix.)

Thank you! Your solution worked! I also found that if you want the same underscore as in the \verb environment, you can use \string_ in \ttfamily.

This doesn't work for every \verb, but in most simple cases it does.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fvextra}

\RecustomVerbatimCommand{\verb}{Verb}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Title}

Text\footnote{\verb|\int|}

\end{frame}

\end{document}

You can also directly use \Verb, of course.


You could store the problematic content in a savebox:
\documentclass{beamer}

\newsavebox\foo

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Title}
Text%
\begin{lrbox}\foo%
\verb|\int|
\end{lrbox}%
\footnote{\usebox\foo}
\end{frame}
\end{document}



The font size is wrong.

@egreg The user can use whatever size they want in the box

Yes, but why not adding \footnotesize yourself? Anyway, I'd prefer to set the box between paragraphs, so you don't have problems with spurious spaces: <blank line>\begin{lrbox}{\foo}\footnotesize\verb|\int|\end{lrbox}<blank line> Text\footnote{\usebox{\foo}}
